# How to make a GRUB Rescue Disc?

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, rescue

I am afraid that my GRUB is corrupted (I do a lot of experiments on my PC) and I know that I will not be able to reinstall Debian (downloading takes up a lot of time).

Also, I am just 13 so I don't know much about it. I want to make a GRUB rescue USB (CD drive doesn't work). Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you wish, so I will answer different, separate questions.

1. Are you asking how to repair your system, should your boot sector get corrupted? If so, the ideal utility for you is [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), a convenient Ubuntu-based utility. All you need to do is put on a USB stick a Ubuntu image (the one that you download in order to install Ubuntu), boot from the stick, choose at the appropriate screen "Try Ubuntu without installing it", then follow the instructions on the Web page I referenced above to download Boot-Repair, then run Boot-Repair using the standard instructions which, in my experience, are normally sufficient to solve most common problems. Please notice that the Ubuntu stick does not keep the downloaded package Boot-Repair (nor any other package, for this matter), so, if you run into the same problem again you will have to retrace the same steps.
2. Should this prove insufficient, you may go [to this Web page of www.distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=Rescue&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active) which lists all distros useful for a system rescue. There are ten to choose from, most people find SystemRescueCd especially helpful, but there are other options.
3. Lastly, there is [Remastersys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys), which is a fantastic utility, which can, according to Wikipedia:

   > Remastersys is a free and open source program for Debian, Ubuntu-based, or derivative software systems that can:
   >   Create a customized Live CD/DVD (a remaster) of Debian and its derivatives.
   >   Back up an entire system, including user data, to an installable Live CD/DVD.

You should not worry about the Live CD/DVD bit, because it is possible to transform a Live CD/DVD image into a bootable stick, easily, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342917/convert-a-live-cd-to-a-bootable-usb).

Now a word about Remastersys. It is in a transition phase because its creator, Fragadelic, has abandoned its development, and has picked it up again inside a different  project. However, for the time being, you can still find the executables for Debian [here](http://www.remastersys.com/), while details about the state of advancement of the new project can be found [here](http://www.os4online.com/2013/04/forking-remastersys-and-state-of-os4.html).

Remember that, when you decide which of these solutions is right for you, you can post in this same forum (but different question) all requests for further clarification you may have.

Comment: okay, i will boot up with liveubuntu and will use boot repair thanks!!!!!